# How Can I use UIkit 2.27.4 with Meteor/React?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, getuikit

Since UIKit 3.0 is in beta I would like to use the stable version UIKIT2.27.4 with React and Meteor, however it is not detecting it. I have imported it as follows:

In meteor client/main.js is as follows

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import '../imports/jquery-3.2.1.min.js';
import '../imports/uikit/css/uikit.min.css';
import '../imports/uikit/js/uikit.min.js';



class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <nav className="uk-navbar">
        <a href="" className="uk-navbar-brand">Kareri</a>
        <ul className="uk-navbar-nav">
          <li>Home </li>
          <li>Trekking</li>
          <li>Hotels</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="" className="uk-navbar-toggle"></a>
</nav>
      </div>
    );

  }
};

Meteor.startup(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
});
```

How can i get uikit to work with REACT and METEOR?

Comment: What means "Not detecting it"? Is the page rendered but the uikit styles are not applied or is there nothing rendered at all or are there errors showing up?

Comment: There are no errors uikit styles are not applied.